# Check if argument is math expression. The case of making the first letter uppercase

Tags: math-mode, macros, capitalization

In this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_{T}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\capitalise}[1]{
  % if string                                                                                                                                 
  \MakeUppercase #1
  % if math expression                                                                                                                        
  #1
} 
\begin{document}
\capitalise{abc}
\capitalise{\pt}
\end{document}
```

`\capitalise` should capitalise the first letter of the argument if it is a string and should leave the argument unchanged if it is a math expression. 
How to check if the argument is a math expression?

Comment: `expl3` contains `\tl_upper_case:n`, which ignores math when changing case.

Comment: See the `textcase` package, it has an alternative to `\MakeUppercase` that in most cases leaves math alone.

Comment: `\ifmmode` tells you if you are in math mode, but obviously this does not work if you switch to math mode inside the argument of `\capitalise`.

Comment: @daleif I checked `textcase` but it nevertheless also capitalised the math expression.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, could you please provide the technical details how to implement `\tl_upper_case:n`

Comment: @Viesturs I have absolutely no clue on how to implement that. Maybe a quick read of [`source3`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/source3.pdf) might give you an idea ;)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Luckily I do ;)

Comment: @Viesturs `textcase` works for me, I posted an answer using it.

Comment: @Viesturs remember to read the manual either use the overload option like David did or use its `\MakeTextUppercase`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\text_titlecase:n` this is trivial

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\capitalise}{m}{\text_titlecase:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_{T}}}
\begin{document}
\capitalise{abc}
\capitalise{\pt}
\end{document}
```

The way this works is by expanding arguments token-by-token and then examining the 'unexpandable' results to see if they can be case-changed. In the case of math mode material, any tokens which produce a `$` start a 'no case changing' approach, which is stopped by a matching `$` (or for `\(`/`\)` pairs). AS `\ensuremath` expands to insert a `$`, this all works 'as expected'.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_{T}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\capitalise}[1]{
  % if string                                                                                                                                 
  \MakeUppercase #1
  % if math expression                                                                                                                        
  #1
} 
\begin{document}
\capitalise{abc}
\capitalise{\pt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. How can I check from which package exactly a command such as `\MakeUppercase` is coming? I tried to use `\show` but I think it didn't work out.

Comment: @Viesturs MakeUppercase is defined in the latex format, and textcase redefines it to be the same as MakeTeXUppercase if you use the overload option